# conservation of critical points under perturbations

Tags: differential-geometry, perturbation-theory

My question is rather vague, but I will try and make it as clear as possible.

Let f be a real function of class $C^2$ on $R^2$, $r,\varepsilon>0$ two positive numbers,  $x$ a critical point (i.e. such that $\nabla f(x)=0$), and $g$ "small", i.e. such that $g$ and all its partial derivatives up to order $2$ are bounded by $\varepsilon$ on $B(x,r)$.

I am looking for a quantitative condition on $f,\varepsilon,r$ that guarantees that $f+g$ has at least one critical point on $B(x,\varepsilon)$.

If for instance $x$ is a local maximum, the answer is quite easy. It is enough to assume that $$2\varepsilon<f(x)-\max_{y\in \partial B(x,r)}f(y),$$ because that condition guarantees that the maximum of $f+g$ on $B(x,r)$ is reached on the interior, therefore this local maximum will be a critical point.

But what if it is a saddle point? Is there a similar condition? I am looking for a condition valid in any dimension, but if you have an answer in dimension $2$ I am still interested. It's ok to bring asumptions on the second or third order derivatives of $f$ if needed. It's also ok to assume that $x$ is non-degenerate, i.e. that the Hessian form at $x$ is non-singular.

Comment: At one point you said $B(x,\varepsilon)$ when I am pretty sure you meant $B(x,r)$. Anyway, it seems to me that an asymptotic version of your result (i.e. a result which is sharp if $\varepsilon$ is sufficiently small) is immediately obtained from the implicit function theorem. Basically, the distance that the critical point moves is $O(\varepsilon)$, and in particular it will be $C\varepsilon+O(\varepsilon^2)$ for a $C$ that depends on some relevant derivatives in the problem. So if $r$ is more than that then $f+g$ has a critical point on $B(x,r)$.

Comment: thanks! you are right it is $B(x,r)$. I don't understand how you choose $\epsilon$ ("sharp") to make sure the critical point does not just disappear after a perturbation of magnitude $\epsilon$. I'm trying to see if there is quantification (almost) as simple as for the local extremum.

Comment: The implicit function theorem implies that the critical point continues to exist for small enough $\varepsilon $ and gives an asymptotic condition describing how small "small" is. I think the only way to annihilate the critical point would be to move it to the boundary or into another critical point but I am not sure about that.

Comment: How do you use the IFT to find a critical point? I don't understand the relation

Comment: You apply IFT to the equation $\nabla h(x)=0$ in a neighborhood of the point $h=f $. This makes $x $ a function of $h $. If the function space is infinite dimensional then there are complications but it does not need to be, for instance you can restrict attention to $h=f+\varepsilon g $ for some fixed $g $.

Comment: Ok, nice idea. It seems to me that in this case, the bound depends on the function g, which is a problem for me. Maybe I need something more algebraic, like the example with the local maximum above.